# Why are we getting intermittent errors connecting to AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

We have C# code (using the AWS .NET SDK) that accesses our AppSettings in AWS DynamoDB, and it works flawlessly on our development PCs.  When we put the code on an EC2 instance, however, we intermittently get errors; sometimes we can access our DynamoDB table and sometimes we can't.  We wrote a small program that strips away all of our other code and just uses the AmazonDynamoDBClient to call the ListTables method.  We put the stripped down code on our EC2 instance and ran it from the command line, and, like our regular application, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Our stripped down code is:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

            ListTablesRequest request = new ListTablesRequest();

            ListTablesResponse response = client.ListTables(request);

            foreach (var tableName in response.TableNames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", tableName);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Exception e1 = e;
            while (e1 != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e1.GetType().ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(e1.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(e1.StackTrace);

                e1 = e1.InnerException;
            }
        }            
    }
```

As you can see, it's pretty straightforward.  These are the errors we (sometimes) get:

```
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException
A WebException with status SendFailure was thrown.

at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.WebExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext executionContext, WebException exception) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\_bcl\WebExceptionHandler.cs:line 44
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ExceptionHandler`1.Handle(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ExceptionHandler.cs:line 38
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler.cs:line 204
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler.cs:line 78
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CallbackHandler.cs:line 45
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Signer.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Signer.cs:line 38
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CredentialsRetriever.cs:line 72
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\RetryHandler\RetryHandler.cs:line 84
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CallbackHandler.cs:line 45
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointResolver.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\EndpointResolver.cs:line 34
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Marshaller.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Marshaller.cs:line 37
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CallbackHandler.cs:line 45
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\ErrorCallbackHandler.cs:line 44
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\MetricsHandler.cs:line 40
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RuntimePipeline.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\RuntimePipeline.cs:line 135
   at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.Invoke[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, IMarshaller`2 marshaller, ResponseUnmarshaller unmarshaller) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AmazonServiceClient.cs:line 192
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.ListTables(ListTablesRequest request) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\DynamoDBv2\Generated\_bcl45\AmazonDynamoDBClient.cs:line 2657
   at DynamoDBTesting.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\mc77vhh8\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsService2\DynamoDBTesting\Program.cs:line 59
14:16:48 Example Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException
14:16:48 Example A WebException with status SendFailure was thrown.
14:16:48 Example    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.WebExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext executionContext, WebException exception) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\_bcl\WebExceptionHandler.cs:line
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ExceptionHandler`1.Handle(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ExceptionHandler.cs:line 38
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler.cs:line 204
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler.cs:line 78
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CallbackHandler.cs:line 45
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Signer.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Signer.cs:line 38
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CredentialsRetriever.cs:line 72
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\RetryHandler\RetryHandler.cs:line 84
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CallbackHandler.cs:line 45
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointResolver.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\EndpointResolver.cs:line 34
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Marshaller.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Marshaller.cs:line 37
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CallbackHandler.cs:line 45
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\ErrorCallbackHandler.cs:line 44
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\MetricsHandler.cs:line 40
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RuntimePipeline.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\RuntimePipeline.cs:line 135
   at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.Invoke[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, IMarshaller`2 marshaller, ResponseUnmarshaller unmarshaller) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AmazonServiceClient.cs:line 192
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.ListTables(ListTablesRequest request) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\DynamoDBv2\Generated\_bcl45\AmazonDynamoDBClient.cs:line 2657
   at DynamoDBTesting.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\mc77vhh8\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsService2\DynamoDBTesting\Program.cs:line 59
System.Net.WebException
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpRequest.GetRequestContent() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\_bcl\HttpWebRequestFactory.cs:line 128
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\HttpHandler.cs:line 81
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Unmarshaller.cs:line 48
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler.cs:line 72
14:16:48 Example Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException
14:16:48 Example The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
14:16:48 Example    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpRequest.GetRequestContent() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\_bcl\HttpWebRequestFactory.cs:line 128
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\HttpHandler.cs:line 81
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Unmarshaller.cs:line 48
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler.cs:line 72
System.IO.IOException
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
14:16:48 Example Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException
14:16:48 Example Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
14:16:48 Example    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
14:16:48 Example Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException
14:16:48 Example An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
14:16:48 Example    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

We are not sure why this is happening.  We verified that our role on the instance has permissions, although since the code works sometimes, we really shouldn't have needed to do so.  Any insight would be most welcome.

Comment: First you must assume that the service is not reliable. With that being said, you should implement some sort of retry logic, with a fail after N tries. The one thing about relying on other companies services, is that you are not in control. You have to fail gracefully, and build it knowing that the service may not be there when you call on it.

Comment: This may not be something related to DynamoDB. You may need to look at how the EC2 instance is provisioned and whether you are using VPC. Check whether you are using EC2 classic or EC2 VPC. Whether the EC2 instance and DynamoDB are in same region ?

Comment: @notionquest - We have a VPC and our EC2 instance is running in the VPC.  Our EC2 instance is in us-east-1a and our DynamoDB table is in US East.

Answer (score 0):

Closed by remote host exceptions are an example of 5XX transient service failures that [should be retried by the client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html#Programming.Errors.MessagesAndCodes). If you get one of these, just retry. If these connection closures continue for a long time, reach out to AWS support or ask for help on the AWS Forum.

Comment: Alexander - The link you gave was helpful in that I was able to determine that my error is happening when I run client.ListTables, not when the client is instantiated.  I get anAmazonServiceException "A WebException with status SecureChannelFailure was thrown."  I am using the default retries of 10, but will adjust that value to see if the behavior changes.

Comment: How frequently do you call list tables?

Comment: In our application, never, but I'm using it in my test program to help diagnose the errors we are getting.  In our real application, we read/write our encrypted AppSettings in a DynamoDB table.